# how to store the heights of a textView in an array or dictionary in iOS 10

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to store the heights of a textview in a dictionary or array. the textview is in an Table view. So I am using the indexpath.row for the array indexes or keys in the  Dictionary. But the indexPath seems to keep changing. Pls advice me here how to store and access them with ease.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "chatbox", for: indexPath) as! TableViewCell

        ...

        //Answer
        cell.textView.text = AppDelegate.chatData[indexPath.row].answer
        ContainerViewController.rowHt[indexPath.row] = cell.textView.contentSize.height

        for (index,ht) in ContainerViewController.rowHt {
            print("\(index) : \(ht)")
        }

        ...
    return cell
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat
{
    return 295.0+(ContainerViewController.rowHt[indexPath.row])!       
}
```

output:

```
4 : 166.5
2 : 166.5
0 : 59.0
1 : 59.0
3 : 59.0
```

output for same After scrolling

```
4 : 166.5
2 : 166.5
0 : 59.0
1 : 166.5
3 : 59.0
```

output for same After adding a value

```
4 : 59.0
5 : 166.5
2 : 59.0
0 : 59.0
1 : 166.5
3 : 59.0
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish by doing this? I need this so I can help provide an answer.

Comment: my text view ranges from having a ht of nothing to having a ht of 200. using the height i can size my table view cell

Comment: You can solve this problem by using constraints & doing this:         
tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 295.0

Comment: that does not really affect my app. It just remains the same.

Comment: you need to provide a project example, otherwise there is no way to help you.

Comment: I am using Storyboards so these are the only two lines i have in the code for the constraints part.

Comment: You need to remove the "heightForRowAt" once you add those two lines of code. If you don't remove that delegate function, it's still going to produce the same results, since you are manually setting the height of each cell.

Comment: so When I do that, My table view cell becomes way too small.

Comment: can you help me with storing the heights?

Comment: how do you have the constraints set up? because you shouldn't need to store the heights...furthermore, why are you using UITextViews?

Answer (score 0):

```
    var myArray = [[String: String]]()
    for (index,ht) in ContainerViewController.rowHt {
        print("\(index) : \(ht)")
        let dict = ["\(index)": "\(ht)"]
        myArray.append(dict)
    }
```

Comment: How to use it in the heightForRowAt method? @Sour